# Word for hobby-drones

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

The word *Unmanned aerial vehicle* describes the military ones that look like planes, e.g:
[image: Military unmanned aircraft]

and Quadcopters, Hexaocopters, etc. that are used both for civil applications like photography and military applications e.g. for surveillance.
[image: Small multi-rotor aircraft]

If I speak about *Unmanned aerial vehicle*, every body thinks of the plan-like (1st image). What is the word for *Unmanned aerial vehicle* without the plan-likes ones?
Is *drone* a correct expression for these flight objects?

Answer (score 3):

Drone is accurate for both, because both a predator and a little quadcopter do not have a pilot in them, and the Predator is sometimes called the "Predator Drone". UAV is more likely to invoke a military context than "drone", but if you want to emphasize the recreational aspect you could try "RC copter" which is short for "radio controlled helicopter" which is what you'd call a toy helicopter you control with a handheld radio device.

However people will often imagine an actual miniature version of a helicopter (with one rotor and a tail rotor) if you say "RC copter", and might call a hexacopter a "drone".

So "drone" is your best bet if you're dealing with people young enough to know about hobby drones, and "RC helicopter" or "RC copter" for older people who might not be familiar with newer drones. Since "RC" toys have been popular in most countries for decades, people will generally know what you mean and understand the recreational context.